# React Native Flatlist BiDirectional

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Has anyone found any elegant way to implement a bidirectional loading flatlist? Kinda like what Twitter does?

I know iOS was given the scrollview that will load bidirectionally, but on Android there is no built in supported way.

I was trying to think of methods to stack the flatlists on top of one another, but it doesn't seem like a very good solution. Any thoughts? The android element extends the Scrollview component on the android library.. I was looking through the source trying to figure out ways to do it.. but am pretty lost